# rewrite a folder so all files display under new rewrite rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Is there a way that I can rewrite a folder so that all the files under that folder follow the same rule? For example:

if i have a folder with say 5 php files (a.php, b.php, c.php, d.php, index.php) in it and i use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^products/storage/?$ /content/products/storage/index.php [QSA,L]
```

is there a way that I can get all the files to show to be accessed like: site.com/products/apples/a.php, site.com/products/apples/b.php, etc. without having to write a rule for each one?

I tried the following but it didnt work.

```
RewriteRule ^products/storage/?$ /content/products/storage/ [QSA,L]
```

I also need it to NOT overwrite my other rules such as:

```
RewriteRule ^products/storage/?$ /content/products/storage/product-name1/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^products/storage/?$ /content/products/storage/product-name2/ [QSA,L]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the trailing `$` on the end of the regex. This will only allow a match if **the full URI** matches `products/storage` (with optional trailing slash) exactly. Instead, try the following and note the absence of the trailing `$` character:

```
RewriteRule ^products/storage/? /content/products/storage/ [QSA,L]
```

This will match anything that starts with products/storage (with optional trailing slash). Alternatively, if you wanted to capture and re-use everything in the URI that followed `products/storage/` you could try:

```
RewriteRule ^products/storage(/?.+)?$ /content/products/storage$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Should you need to preserve other `RewriteRule`s as your updated question suggests, you should look to add a `RewriteCond` condition like so:

```
RewriteCond !^products/storage/?$
RewriteRule ^products/storage(/?.+)?$ /content/products/storage$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` tells the `RewriteRule` to only process if the condition is not met.

Comment: hmmm well I'm getting an issue now with other rules not working.  So for instance I have 
    RewriteRule ^products/storage/?$ /content/products/storage/product-name1/ [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^products/storage/?$ /content/products/storage/product-name2/ [QSA,L]

now those don't work if I add the rule you gave me

Comment: Then you need to add `RewriteCond` conditions prior to the `RewriteRule` to expressly prevent it from applying if those conditions are met ... this is information you should update in your question